# Disable TLS below 1.2 in Azure cosmosDB account

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-cosmosdb, tls1.2

Cannot find any setting for TLS neither in Azure portal nor in CLI. I read they enforce 1.2 for account without any clients using older versions of TLS. But I am able to connect to my with TLS1.0, 1.1 and 1.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do that in the azure portal or cli currently, you need to contact Microsoft - `azurecosmosdbtls@service.microsoft.com`.

Source - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-security#how-does-azure-cosmos-db-secure-my-database

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to teach my terraform script to send an email whenever new cosmos account is created :D

Answer (score 0):

To disable TLS < 1.2 you currently still need to open a support ticket.